# Passing Column Names from a tuple to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, data-science, namedtuple

My Scenario looks like this, where i have identified the columns having NaN values using,

```
nan_cols=tuple(train.columns[train.isnull().sum()>0])
```

Now, I need to find the correlation between these columns and target variable. So I tried something like,

`train[[nan_cols,'SalePrice']].corr()` and got the below error:

> KeyError: "[('LotFrontage', 'Alley', 'MasVnrType', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtQual', >'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'Electrical', >'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', >'GarageCond', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'MiscFeature')] not in index"

So, is there a way for me to pass my column names as a tuple in pandas? I tried the same with list and Series as well but as they were mutable, it didnt work out. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

By this line

```
train[[nan_cols,'SalePrice']].corr()
```

you trying to access **rows**. Also `[nan_cols,'SalePrice']` gives a **list** of a **tuple** and an **object**: `[(tuple),object]`

A good practice is to use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in order to locate required rows/columns. To access columns I would suggest:

```
train.loc[:,[*nan_cols,'SalePrice']].corr()
```

or

```
train[:,[*nan_cols,'SalePrice']].corr()
```

More on * operator you can read in [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one:

```
nan_cols=[train.columns[train.isnull().sum()>0])
train[nan_cols + ['SalePrice']].corr()
```

Why do we need to pass columns as a tuple. To index in second line, we need only a list of columns.